# Fill an unclosed bezier path in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, sprite-kit, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to create an image similar to the one on the left. I have a NSBezier path (not a closed path) but when I fill it, It seems to only produce the image on the right. I want to fill the path but only the looped part. Any suggestions?

[image: The loops on the left is what I am trying to create]

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(board.size)
            if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
                if let path = snake.path {
                    context.setShouldAntialias(false)
                    let transformedPath = CGMutablePath()
                    transformedPath.addPath(path, transform: transform)
                    context.addPath(transformedPath)
                    context.setLineJoin(.round)
                    context.setLineCap(.round)
                    context.setLineWidth(snake.thickness)
                    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.magenta.cgColor)
                    context.strokePath()
                    context.fillPath()

                }

                if let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.cgImage {
                    board.texture = SKTexture(cgImage: newImage)
                }
            }

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any `fill` call in your code.

Comment: Did you mean *"It seems to only produce the image on the **right**"* ?

Comment: Apologies, I updates the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't read the [`strokePath` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1454490-strokepath), which says:

> The current path is cleared as a side effect of calling this function.

So by the time you call `fillPath`, the current path is empty. There's nothing to fill. You need to set the path again with another call to `context.addPath(transformedPath)` before calling `fillPath`.

If you want to fill first and then stroke, you call use `context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)` instead. This method fills, then strokes the current path (and then clears the current path).

Also, you didn't set the context's fill color. The default fill color is black, which might not be the color you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I should have read the documentation more thoroughly...